# X variable changes on the last try of simple guessing game, C++

Tags: c++

I'm somewhat new to coding and C++ and all. I tried to make a guessing game that stores the previous guesses in an array that will display after every failed try.

The problem is, no matter what I input, the third try will always register as correct and the x variable, which is the random number, will change to whatever I input as the y[2]. The code worked perfectly before I added the array to the y variable, and adjusted the rest of the code to fit that.

I also cout-ed the variables to try to debug it. Any and all help is much appreciated. Thanks! ;)

```
//Generating Random Number:

#include <cstdlib>  // or <stdlib.h>
#include <ctime>    // or <time.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int x;
    int y[2];
    int z = 3;
    int i;
    bool done = false;
    srand(time(NULL));      
    x = rand() % 10 + 1;
    i = 0;
    int s;
    s = x;
    while (done == false)
    {
        cout << "Guess a number between 1 to 10.\n";
        switch (i)
        {
            case 0: break;
            case 1:
                cout << "Previous guesses:\n" << y[0] << endl << endl; break;
            case 2:
                cout << "Previous guesses:\n" << y[0] << endl << y[1] << endl << endl; break;
        }
        cin >> y[i];
        cout << "y[" << i << "] = " << y[i] << endl;
        cout << "s = " << s << endl;
        if (y[i] > s)
        {
            z--;
            i++;
            cout << "\nLower!\n" << "Tries remaining: " << z << endl << endl;
            if (z == 0)
            {
                cout << "\nSorry! You ran out of tries. :(";
                Sleep (2000);
                done = true;
            }
        }
        else if (y[i] < s)
        {
            z--;
            i++;
            cout << "\nHigher!\n" << "Tries remaining: " << z << endl << endl;
            if (z == 0)
            {
                cout << "\nSorry! You ran out of tries. :(";
                Sleep (2000);
                done = true;
            }
        }
        else if (y[i] == s)
        {
            cout << "i = " << i << endl;
            cout << "\nCongratulations!\n" << "Your number is " << y[i] << ".\n" << "Tries remaining: " << z;
            done = true;
        }
    }
    return(0);
}
```

Comment: when `i == 2`, `y[i]` writes out of bounds

Comment: Odd, I thought that arrays would consider it as 0, 1, and 2, therefore making it 3 elements, which is all that is needed for the program. It did work though. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Compile with all warnings & debug info (`g++ -Wall -Wextra -g` if using [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)....).... Then **use the debugger** (`gdb`)

Answer (score 0):

`int y[2]` means that you create an array with a size of 2 (which can hold two elements).

What's more, `vector` or `std::array` is preferred than the built in array